# Using same object in multiple tabs in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a `shinydashboard` app and I want to be able to use the same object in multiple tabs. For example, in the code below I've created the `radioButtons` `data1` and `data2`, both of which correspond to the `Model1` and `Model2` tabs, respectively. However, is there a way to create one `radioButton`, named `data`, and have it be used in both tabs? Since I want the value for this to remain the same across all tabs, it would save time and coding space to have only one instance.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title='Title'),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem('Models', tabName='Models',
        menuSubItem('Model1', tabName='Model1'),
        menuSubItem('Model2', tabName='Model2')
      ),
      tags$head(tags$script(HTML('$(document).ready(function() {$(".treeview-menu").css("display", "block");})')))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName='Model1',
        h1("Model 1"),
        radioButtons('data1', 'Select Data',
          choices=list("Use Old Data"='old', "Use New Data"='new')
        ),
        verbatimTextOutput('out1')
      ),
      tabItem(tabName='Model2',
        h1("Model 2"),
        radioButtons('data2', 'Select Data',
          choices=list("Use Old Data"='old', "Use New Data"='new')
        ),
        verbatimTextOutput('out2')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out1 <- renderPrint(input$data1)
  output$out2 <- renderPrint(input$data2)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863898/r-shiny-multiple-use-in-ui-of-same-renderui-in-server